# Maximizing volume in Calculus

Tags: calculus, volume

An open box is to be created from a flat piece of cardboard $36$ inches square by cutting a square from each corner and then folding up the edges. How long should the side of the square being cut out in order to maximize the volume of the box created, and what is the volume of the box created?
So far I have $f(x)=x(6-2x)^2$. Would $f'(x)=2x(6-3x)$ and the critical points being $x=0$ and $x=3$?

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem so far? What have you tried? The more you can tell us, the more we will be able to tailor our answers to your needs, and the more likely that someone will be willing to help you.

Comment: What is the function to be maximized? What is the constraint function? Please include in your question what work you've tried so far; without such context, this question is likely to be deemed off-topic.

Comment: Right now the problem is overwhelming me and I don't know where to start. I feel like once I figure out what the first steps are I'll be all set then

Comment: Hint, step 1 is to formulate the volume of the box, from the one variable that you can control - the length of the edges of the squares.  Step 2 - find the first derivative.  Step 3 look for 'special' points in the derivative.

Comment: Are the special points x=0 and x=3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the side of the square you're cutting out is $x$ inches, then the box created will have dimensions, in inches, $(6-2x) \times (6-2x) \times x$. Hence, you need to maximize $f(x) = x(6-2x)^2$, where $0 \leq x \leq 3$.

Comment: Would I do 2x(6-2x). And then have X=0, and X=3?

Comment: You get that $f'(x) = (6-2x)^2 -4(6-2x) = (6-2x)(2-2x)$, and so, ou see that the critical points are $x=0,1$. However, $x=0$ is not viable since you cannot cut nothing away.